# Slice recording audio file, given start and end timestamps

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I am trying to store a rtmp stream in audio file using ffmpeg tool. 
Following is the command I am using -

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:9000/app/test-stream -c:a aac -y output.aac
```

I need to slice through the `output.aac` file while its also getting recorded. Given a start and end time, I am trying to use ffmpeg's `-ss` feature.

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 10 -i output.aac -y sliced.aac
```

But this gives error -

```
ffmpeg version N-85581-ge22d495538-static http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.1 (Debian 5.4.1-8) 20170304
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-5 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gray --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      55. 61.100 / 55. 61.100
  libavcodec     57. 92.100 / 57. 92.100
  libavformat    57. 72.101 / 57. 72.101
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 84.101 /  6. 84.101
  libswscale      4.  7.101 /  4.  7.101
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
  libpostproc    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x3bb54e0] moov atom not found
output.aac: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Can anyone help me with this issue.

Comment: Show the full console output of your slice command.

Comment: Hey Mulvya, I have edited the question.